# Counting the number of requests per second in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I am new to **Python** and **Tornado** WebServer.
I am trying to figure out the number of request and number of requests/second in my server side code. I am using Tornadio2 to implement websockets.

Kindly take a look at the following code and let me know, what modification can be done to it.
I am using the RequestHandler.prepare() to bottleneck all the requests and using a list as it is immutable to store the count.

### Consider all modules are included

```
    count=[0]
    class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
     """Regular HTTP handler to serve the chatroom page"""
       def prepare(self):
       count[0]=count[0]+1

       def get(self):
         self.render('index1.html')

   class SocketIOHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
      def get(self):
         self.render('../socket.io.js')

  partQue=Queue.Queue()
  class ChatConnection(tornadio2.conn.SocketConnection):
        participants = set()
        def on_open(self, info):
           self.send("Welcome from the server.")
           self.participants.add(self)     

       def on_message(self, message):
            partQue.put(message)
            time.sleep(10)
            self.qmes=partQue.get()
            for p in self.participants:
                p.send(self.qmes+" "+str(count[0]))
            partQue.task_done()   

      def on_close(self):
           self.participants.remove(self)
           partQue.join()

 # Create tornadio server
  ChatRouter = tornadio2.router.TornadioRouter(ChatConnection)

 # Create socket application
  sock_app = tornado.web.Application(
      ChatRouter.urls, 
      flash_policy_port = 843,
      flash_policy_file = op.join(ROOT, 'flashpolicy.xml'),
      socket_io_port = 8002)

 # Create HTTP application
 http_app = tornado.web.Application(
      [(r"/", IndexHandler), (r"/socket.io.js", SocketIOHandler)])

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     import logging
     logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

     # Create http server on port 8001
     http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(http_app)
     http_server.listen(8001)

     # Create tornadio server on port 8002, but don't start it yet
     tornadio2.server.SocketServer(sock_app, auto_start=False)

     # Start both servers
     tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Also, I am confused about every Websocket messages. Does each Websocket event got to server in the form of an HTTP request? or a Socket.IO request?

Answer (score 2):

I use [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) - excellent tool for testing requests if your running on linux. Example

```
siege http://localhost:8000/?q=yourquery -c10 -t10s
```

-c10 = 10 concurrent users 
-t10s = 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Tornadio2 has built-in statistics module, which includes incoming connections/s and other counters.

Check following example: https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio2/tree/master/examples/stats

Answer (score 0):

When testing applications, always approach performance testing with a healthy appreciation for the [uncertainty principle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle).

If you want to test a server, hook up two PCs to a HUB where you can monitor traffic from one going to the other. Then bang the hell out of the server. There are a variety of tools for doing this, just look for **web load testing** tools.

Answer (score 0):

Normal HTTP requests in Tornado create a new `RequestHandler` instance, which persists until the connection is terminated.

WebSockets use persistent connections. One `WebSocketHandler` instance is created, and each message sent by the browser to the server calls the `on_message` method.

From what I understand, Socket.IO/Tornad.IO will use WebSockets if supported by the browser, falling back to long polling.